# Divergence Funtion result issue

Tags: pine-script

I try to implement a function to find short term RSI divergences. I want it to work like this:

- Find last RSI pivot
- Compare it to previous Pivots
- If there is a Divergence, set counter plus one
- And if my counter over 0 - show a divergence char at bar.

But it doesn't work.

```
study("RSI short term divergence", overlay=true)

//Inputs
lookback = input(defval=34, title='Lookback for RSI divergence, bars', minval=1, type=input.integer)
len = input(defval=3, title='Pivot confirmation, bars', minval=1, type=input.integer)

//RSI
rsi = rsi(close, 14)

//Variables
pivotLow = pivotlow(rsi, len, 1)

//Function

func_short(pivsback) =>
    count_s = 0
    for i = 1 to pivsback
        rsiLast_s = valuewhen(pivotLow, rsi[1], 0)
        priceLast_s = valuewhen(pivotLow, close[1], 0)
        barLast_s = valuewhen(pivotLow, bar_index[1], 0)
        rsiWas_s = valuewhen(pivotLow, rsi[1], i)
        priceWas_s = valuewhen(pivotLow, close[1], i)
        barWas_s = valuewhen(pivotLow, bar_index[1], i)
        count_s = if (rsiLast_s > rsiWas_s) and (priceWas_s > priceLast_s) and (barLast_s-barWas_s)<lookback
            count_s := count_s + 1
    count_s

divShort = func_short(3)>0

plotchar(divShort, location=location.abovebar, color=color.white, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valuewhen()`, like many other built-ins, can't be used in `for` loops with variable arguments. See [this usrman section](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html?highlight=loop#for-statement) for an explanation.

Your options are:

1. Use a structure like this to pre-evaluate a preset quantity of pivots and then run your logic on them:

```
//@version=4
study("Max Pivots", "", true)
legs = input(4)
pH = pivothigh(legs, legs)
newPH = not na(pH)
p00 = valuewhen(newPH, high[legs], 00)
p01 = valuewhen(newPH, high[legs], 01)
p02 = valuewhen(newPH, high[legs], 02)
maxPH = max(p00, p01, p02)
plot(maxPH)
plotchar(newPH, "newPH", "•", location.abovebar, offset = - legs)
plotchar(newPH, "newPH", "▲", location.top)
```

2. Run an embedded `for` loop to hunt past bars for past pivot values, which I don't recommend as it will be very slow.

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me a lot